# Variabilité d'adjectifs débutant par ANTI-

Tags: pluriel, préfixes

Plusieurs adjectifs débutant par ANTI- sont variables, alors que plusieurs ne le sont pas.

Voici quelques exemples d'adjectifs variables :

- « antichoc »
- « antichar »
- « anticapitaliste »
- « antidreyfusard »
- « antifébrile »

et voici quelques exemples d'adjectifs invariables :

- « anticriminalité »
- « antifeu »
- « antimafia »
- « antisida »
- « antitout »

Ma question est donc : existe-t-il une règle nous disant quand l'adjectif est variable et quand il ne l'est pas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En règle générale, si le préfixe *anti-* est suivi d'un ajdectif, il forme l'adjectif contraire, et on accorde. Si le préfixe *anti-* est suivi d'un nom ou autre type de mot, il forme une locution adjectivale que l'on n'accorde pas. Donc : *des médicaments antifébriles*, *des armes anti-aériennes*, mais *des couvertures antifeu*.

Toutefois, quand le composé est suffisamment utilisé, il devient accepté comme un mot indépendant de son étymologie, et alors on l'accorde comme n'importe quel autre adjectif. Par exemple, *des armes antichar* ou *des armes antichars*, *des revêtements antiglisse* ou *des revêtements antiglisses*. L'exemple des chars est facilité par le fait qu'une arme lutte contre les chars en général, et on trouve aussi *une arme antichars*.

La marque du féminin met plus de temps à survenir : on n'écrit pas (pas encore ?) « *des armes antichares* ».

Le préfixe *anti*- est très productif, beaucoup de mots sont formés à cause d'un besoin ponctuel. Il y a donc un gros potentiel de variation sur un mot donné, tant qu'il n'est pas suffisamment courant pour se trouver dans les dictionnaires en tant que tel.